# Autocomplete in Javascript /HTML - find array index of clicked value

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete

Its my first post, so thanks in advance,  and I hope I have posted correctly.
I am using the "autocomplete" code at [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp)

(JS part of the code is below).
On event "click", I need to find the *array index* of the clicked result.
In my adapted version I have added a hidden value for the array index under with an "id" of 'place_Index'.
However, the Event Listener (and !e.target!) return the string result from the **Input text box** (i.e. not the inner.HTML / hidden values).

JS code below

Even if I find a way to access the 'place_Index' value, the result is the index of the *first* item in the autocomplete-list, not the index for the **selected** item.
I am still a 'noob' so would rather achieve this with Vanilla JS rather than via a Library / plug in.
I genuinely have searched  Stackoverflow, and the web, but cant locate an answer that produces the required result. Thanks in advance.

```
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
  var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      /*for each item in the array...*/
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
          /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          /*make the matching letters bold:*/
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
**          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' name = 'place_Index' id = 'place_Index' value='" + Div_Array_Counter + "'>";**
          /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
              b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              /*close the list of autocompleted values,
              (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
        increase the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus++;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
        decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus--;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
      x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
    }
  }
}
/*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    closeAllLists(e.target);
});
}
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries);
```

Comment: Hey, can you please be a bit more precise on the problem and don't put your whole code in here only a minimal demo ;) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you declare your for loop counter with let, eg `for (let i = 0;...` you can just use `i` within your listener.

Comment: Thanks both. Appreciated. In the event listener, how can I find the index of the clicked item? E.g. before the "click listener" is invoked, the array has 5 items.  The user clicks item 3. How can I get the listener to identify that it was item 3 which was clicked?

Comment: Sorry I should have added that the array (of place names) has many duplicate names - but I want to keep the duplicates and identify which of the duplicates has been selected.

Comment: You can add a data attribute before your `a.appendChild(b)`, like so `b.setAttribute("data-id",i)`, and then capture that in your click event handler with, for example `e.target.getAttribute("data-id")`. You would also need to decide on what to do when something is selected, then retyped fully (for whatever reason), and you click anywhere else in the document, except on the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I offer you my "library" for autocomplete. I probably used the same W3Schools tutorial because code is similar.

I also "connected" it with google suggest, but you should override the function `suggest(word, callback)` to search your list of countries.

```js
function autocomplete(inp, foo_selected) {
  /**
   * must be inside relative wrapper or a <div class="autocomplete">
   */
  var noop = function() {}
  var currentFocus;

  function suggest(word, callback) {
    var script = document.createElement('script')
    var src = 'https://www.google.com/complete/search?client=gws-wiz&q=' + encodeURIComponent(word)
    script.async = true;
    script.src = src;
    document.head.appendChild(script)

    window.google = {
      ac: {
        h: callback
      }
    }
  }

  inp.addEventListener("input", function(ev) {
    var container, item, val = this.value;
    if (!val) {
      closeAllLists();
      return false;
    }
    var self = this;

    function foo_got_arr(arr) {
      closeAllLists();

      var terms = arr[0]
      terms = terms.map(word => stripHtml(word[0]));

      arr = terms;

      currentFocus = -1;
      container = document.createElement("DIV");
      container.setAttribute("id", self.id + "autocomplete-list");
      container.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      self.parentNode.appendChild(container);
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
          item = document.createElement("DIV");
          item.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          item.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          item.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          item.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
            inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
            closeAllLists();
            typeof foo_selected === 'function' && foo_selected(inp.value);
          });
          container.appendChild(item);
        }
      }
    }

    suggest(val, foo_got_arr)

  });

  function addActive(x) {
    if (!x) {
      return false;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");

    inp.value = x[currentFocus].innerText;
    caret2End(inp)

  }

  function closeAllLists(elem) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elem != x[i] && elem != inp) {
        x[i].remove();
      }
    }

    window.google = {
      ac: {
        h: noop
      }
    }
  }

  function stripHtml(html) {
    var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
    tmp.innerHTML = html;
    return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
  }

  function caret2End(input) {
    input.blur();
    setTimeout(function() {
      input.focus();
    })
  }

  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev) {
    var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    if (x) {
      x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
    }
    if (ev.keyCode == 40) {
      currentFocus++;
      addActive(x);
      ev.preventDefault();
    } else if (ev.keyCode == 38) {
      currentFocus--;
      addActive(x);
      ev.preventDefault();
    } else if (ev.keyCode == 27) {
      closeAllLists();
    } else if (ev.keyCode == 13) {
      closeAllLists();
      typeof foo_selected === 'function' && foo_selected(inp.value);

    }
  });

  document.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
    closeAllLists(ev.target);
  });
}


// USAGE:

autocomplete(input, function(value) {
  alert("you chosen: " + value)
})
```

```css
.autocomplete {
  /*the container must be positioned relative! */
  position: relative;
}

.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 0 .2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  opacity: 1;
}

.autocomplete-active {
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="autocomplete">
  <input id="input" placeholder="Search...">
</div>
```

Here's a more generic version!

```js
function autocomplete(inp, foo_suggest, foo_selected) {
  /**
   * must be inside relative wrapper or a <div class="autocomplete">
   */
  var currentFocus;

  inp.addEventListener("input", function(ev) {
    var container, item, val = this.value;
    if (!val) {
      closeAllLists();
      return false;
    }
    var self = this;

    function foo_got_arr(arr) {
      closeAllLists();

      currentFocus = -1;
      container = document.createElement("DIV");
      container.setAttribute("id", self.id + "autocomplete-list");
      container.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      self.parentNode.appendChild(container);
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
          item = document.createElement("DIV");
          item.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          item.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          item.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          item.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
            inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
            closeAllLists();
            typeof foo_selected === 'function' && foo_selected(inp.value);
          });
          container.appendChild(item);
        }
      }
    }

    foo_suggest(val, foo_got_arr)

  });

  function addActive(x) {
    if (!x) {
      return false;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");

    inp.value = x[currentFocus].innerText;
    caret2End(inp)

  }

  function closeAllLists(elem) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elem != x[i] && elem != inp) {
        x[i].remove();
      }
    }
  }

  function caret2End(input) {
    input.blur();
    setTimeout(function() {
      input.focus();
    })
  }

  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev) {
    var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    if (x) {
      x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
    }
    if (ev.keyCode == 40) {
      currentFocus++;
      addActive(x);
      ev.preventDefault();
    } else if (ev.keyCode == 38) {
      currentFocus--;
      addActive(x);
      ev.preventDefault();
    } else if (ev.keyCode == 27) {
      closeAllLists();
    } else if (ev.keyCode == 13) {
      closeAllLists();
      typeof foo_selected === 'function' && foo_selected(inp.value);

    }
  });

  document.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
    closeAllLists(ev.target);
  });
}


// USAGE:

function suggest_google(word, callback) {
  var script = document.createElement('script')
  var src = 'https://www.google.com/complete/search?client=gws-wiz&q=' + encodeURIComponent(word)
  script.async = true;
  script.src = src;
  document.head.appendChild(script)

  var noop = function() {}

  var foo_normlize = (function(result) {
    var arr = result[0].map(function(item) {
      return stripHtml(item[0])
    })

    window.google = {
      ac: {
        h: noop
      }
    }
    callback(arr)
  })

  function stripHtml(html) {
    var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
    tmp.innerHTML = html;
    return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
  }

  window.google = {
    ac: {
      h: foo_normlize
    }
  }
}

function suggest_country(word, callback) {

  const countries = [`Afghanistan`, `Albania`, `Algeria`, `Andorra`, `Angola`, `Antigua and Barbuda`, `Argentina`, `Armenia`, `Australia`, `Austria`, `Azerbaijan`, `Bahamas`, `Bahrain`, `Bangladesh`, `Barbados`, `Belarus`, `Belgium`, `Belize`, `Benin`, `Bhutan`, `Bolivia`, `Bosnia and Herzegovina`, `Botswana`, `Brazil`, `Brunei`, `Bulgaria`, `Burkina Faso`, `Burundi`, `Côte d'Ivoire`, `Cabo Verde`, `Cambodia`, `Cameroon`, `Canada`, `Central African Republic`, `Chad`, `Chile`, `China`, `Colombia`, `Comoros`, `Congo (Congo-Brazzaville)`, `Costa Rica`, `Croatia`, `Cuba`, `Cyprus`, `Czechia (Czech Republic)`, `Democratic Republic of the Congo`, `Denmark`, `Djibouti`, `Dominica`, `Dominican Republic`, `Ecuador`, `Egypt`, `El Salvador`, `Equatorial Guinea`, `Eritrea`, `Estonia`, `Eswatini (fmr. "Swaziland")`, `Ethiopia`, `Fiji`, `Finland`, `France`, `Gabon`, `Gambia`, `Georgia`, `Germany`, `Ghana`, `Greece`, `Grenada`, `Guatemala`, `Guinea`, `Guinea-Bissau`, `Guyana`, `Haiti`, `Holy See`, `Honduras`, `Hungary`, `Iceland`, `India`, `Indonesia`, `Iran`, `Iraq`, `Ireland`, `Israel`, `Italy`, `Jamaica`, `Japan`, `Jordan`, `Kazakhstan`, `Kenya`, `Kiribati`, `Kuwait`, `Kyrgyzstan`, `Laos`, `Latvia`, `Lebanon`, `Lesotho`, `Liberia`, `Libya`, `Liechtenstein`, `Lithuania`, `Luxembourg`, `Madagascar`, `Malawi`, `Malaysia`, `Maldives`, `Mali`, `Malta`, `Marshall Islands`, `Mauritania`, `Mauritius`, `Mexico`, `Micronesia`, `Moldova`, `Monaco`, `Mongolia`, `Montenegro`, `Morocco`, `Mozambique`, `Myanmar (formerly Burma)`, `Namibia`, `Nauru`, `Nepal`, `Netherlands`, `New Zealand`, `Nicaragua`, `Niger`, `Nigeria`, `North Korea`, `North Macedonia`, `Norway`, `Oman`, `Pakistan`, `Palau`, `Palestine State`, `Panama`, `Papua New Guinea`, `Paraguay`, `Peru`, `Philippines`, `Poland`, `Portugal`, `Qatar`, `Romania`, `Russia`, `Rwanda`, `Saint Kitts and Nevis`, `Saint Lucia`, `Saint Vincent and the Grenadines`, `Samoa`, `San Marino`, `Sao Tome and Principe`, `Saudi Arabia`, `Senegal`, `Serbia`, `Seychelles`, `Sierra Leone`, `Singapore`, `Slovakia`, `Slovenia`, `Solomon Islands`, `Somalia`, `South Africa`, `South Korea`, `South Sudan`, `Spain`, `Sri Lanka`, `Sudan`, `Suriname`, `Sweden`, `Switzerland`, `Syria`, `Tajikistan`, `Tanzania`, `Thailand`, `Timor-Leste`, `Togo`, `Tonga`, `Trinidad and Tobago`, `Tunisia`, `Turkey`, `Turkmenistan`, `Tuvalu`, `Uganda`, `Ukraine`, `United Arab Emirates`, `United Kingdom`, `United States of America`, `Uruguay`, `Uzbekistan`, `Vanuatu`, `Venezuela`, `Vietnam`, `Yemen`, `Zambia`, `Zimbabwe`]

  var result = countries.filter(function(country) {
    return country.toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase()) >= 0
  })

  callback(result)
}

autocomplete(input, suggest_google, function(value) {
  alert("you chosen: " + value)
})

autocomplete(input2, suggest_country, function(value) {
  alert("you chosen: " + value)
})
```

```css
.autocomplete {
  /*the container must be positioned relative! */
  position: relative;
}

.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 0 .2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  opacity: 1;
}

.autocomplete-active {
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex">

  <div class="autocomplete">
    <input id="input" placeholder="Search google...">
  </div>

  <div class="autocomplete">
    <input id="input2" placeholder="Search country...">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I am still playing around linking my array to your code but wanted to thank you for your help / work.

Comment: I made it more generic. `autocomplete(inp, foo_suggest, foo_selected)`

Comment: Thanks so much. I can work with that. Really appreciated!